# Trouble with Vertical Centering of Block element in mobile Safari

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

I am trying to vertically center a div (of unknown height) within another div. I followed a tutorial [here](http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) and it seems to display correctly in Firefox v33 (desktop), IE11, and Chrome v39, but it does not display correctly in mobile Safari 7 or 8 - check out my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ef0dev/2f8d7cpn/5/), or the html/css is below.

*Why does mobile Safari treat this differently than other browsers, and what are my alternatives?* I already tried flexbox, and that didn't work in mobile Safari either. I know vertical centering can be tricky. Should I just give up and assign the element-to-be-centered a fixed height? If the height is fixed, I can make it work - but there are other situations where the height truly could be variable, so I'd like to know how to make it work without a fixed height.

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">This is a test</div>
</div>

.outer
{
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;    
    height: 100px;
}

.inner
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    color: red;
}
```

**Mobile Safari**
[image: Vertical Centering in Mobile Safari]

**Firefox, IE11, Chrome**
[image: Vertical Centering in Firefox, IE11, & Chrome]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the webkit prefix for translate. Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2f8d7cpn/6/). [Caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=translate) is a great site for future reference in these situations.

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">This is a test</div>
</div>

.outer
{
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;    
    height: 100px;
}

.inner
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved it. I need to learn more about these prefixes.

Comment: Thank you!  I was pounding my head with the same problem.